# Residuals from R regression of a data subset

Tags: r, regression

I would like to get regression residuals but only a residuals subset from data:

My R code:

```
reg = lm(Y ~ X1+X2+.....+Xn,data=fic)
step_reg = step(reg, direction= "both")
summary(step_reg)
```

`fic` is a dataframe with n columns called `X1`, `X2`, ...`Xn`.

To get all residuals: `step_reg2$residuals`

But I would like to get residuals only for rows which respect criteria like for example `X1 = 'xxxx'`
What could be the solution, please?

Comment: Maybe: `step_reg2$residuals[fic$X1 == 'xxxx' ]`

Comment: Ok it's wonderfull. I 'll test your proposition immediately!

Comment: Are there any missing values in the Xs?

Comment: No not missing values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data you used for the regression to subset the residuals like:

```
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
step_reg <- step(reg, direction= "both")
step_reg$residuals[iris$Species=="setosa"]
```

In case there are missing values:

```
x <- iris
x[1,2] <- NA
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=x)
reg$residuals[iris[names(reg$residuals), "Species"] == "setosa"]
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I have a regression: reg2bis = lm(f, data=fic) 
step_reg2bis = step(reg2bis, direction= "both")